# Netsuite: How to getDataCenter in SuiteScript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I wish to know how to get dynamic data center url.
I have checked in nets and knew that getdatacenterurl only applicable for REST while I wish to do the same in Suitescript.

The reason for this is because currently I am hardcoded the data center in URL and this will not work if the customer change their data center in future.

I know nlapiResolveURL only help to generate the later part of URL and we still need to define the base domain at the first place.

Any helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little hackish but you could use nlapiResolveURL to ask for the external URL of a Suitelet and then replace forms with system and then slice the first part before app. Something like this:

```
var externalURL = nlapiResolveURL('SUITELET', 'customscript_xxxx', 'customdeploy_xxxx', true);
externalURL = externalURL.replace('forms', 'system');
var dataCenter = externalURL.slice(0, externalURL.search('app'));
```

Note: The suitelet doesn't need to be public, you can use an internal one and it should still return the first part of the url.

Comment: Great hack. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: If you're using 2.0 instead of 1.0, then in the 2017.1 release, the `N/url` module has a `resolveDomain` method.